# Can abp suite target a razor class library (RCL) for UI components/pages?

Tags: blazor-server-side, abp, maui-blazor, razor-class-library

I'm new to abp, and I've managed to follow a few tutorials to get familiar with the basics of the framework, but I can't figure out how to generate a solution with an extra layer between the .HttpApi and .Web projects shown below.

[abp diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YfYGj.png)

My goal is to use Blazor server as my UI and Maui/Blazor hybrid as my mobile front end (using BlazorWebView). I can generate a Blazor server solution or a Maui hybrid solution, but I really want most UI (including the CRUD pages generated by Abp Suite) to reside in a Razor Class Library (RCL) project that is reusable by both the Blazor server and Maui hybrid UIs.

Is this an available template, or how could I customize an available template to achieve this?

I'd settle for a solution that simply adds the RCL with Blazor server so it's easy to add the Maui hybrid project later or a suggested method to reuse UI from the Blazor server project in a Maui hybrid app.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [module template](https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/Startup-Templates/Module) and create a module with UI. There are host applications that you can test your UI within this template.

Afterwards, you can create a new application and add your UI libraries to your application. ABP applications templates are built upon this modular application building and the some of the modules that contain UI libraries are already pre-installed. You can examine the [application templates](https://github.com/abpframework/abp/blob/2318705cbace2b78a3f126e05c5714b16c55ac1e/templates/app/aspnet-core/src/MyCompanyName.MyProjectName.Web/MyCompanyName.MyProjectName.Web.csproj#L55-L58) to have better understanding.